# How to handle HTTP Expect header in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I am using the curl command to send a file through a POST request. I'm not using the PHP curl library. However, the curl command is too polite and sends an Expect header. How should I handle it on the server side? I know that the server must return a 100-continue response, but how to it will continue receiving the file? The $_FILES array is always empty.

This is what I sent to the server:

```
/usr/bin/curl -sS -X POST -T "/tmp/phpuPfIDd" http://localhost/stats/rgateway/index.php/data 2>&1
```

And the server-side code would be something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET':
        # Do something if it is a GET request   
        break;

    case 'POST':    
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        if (array_key_exists('Expect', $headers)) {
                 # What should I do here in order to receive uploaded the file?
        }   
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks. Now I've edited the post.

Comment: `-T, --upload-file <file>

This transfers the specified local file to the remote URL. If there is no file part in the specified URL, Curl will append the local file name. NOTE that you must use a trailing / on the last directory to really prove to Curl that there is no file name or curl will think that your last directory name is the remote file name to use. That will most likely cause the upload operation to fail`

Comment: Also your header `Expect` has no value, thus invalid. Apache drops invalid headers faster than a hot pan. I'm not sure why you don't use the php cURL module. It's easier to use. If you want to upload a file, you need to use the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Hi Charlotte, and thanks. The -H "Expect:" was not supposed to be there. So I corrected again the post. I just added it later in an attempt to see what happened if I remove the Expect header. The question is how a code to handle an Expect header should look like on the server side.

Comment: Thanks. I've read that. But I cannot figure out how the server code should look like. The curl command sends an Expect header, the server responds with a 100-continue and then what? Does the curl client sent another POST without the Expect header? Otherwise, how the server catches the file if the POST has been already processed?

Comment: The whole process of this gets handled by the web server (Apache or Nginx) https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122627/discussion-between-user2641103-and-charlotte-dunois).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, this should be handled by your web server, with no need for PHP to worry about such low-level things.

Relevant sections from `man curl`:

```
   -0, --http1.0
          (HTTP) Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.0 instead of using its
          internally preferred: HTTP 1.1.

   --expect100-timeout <seconds>
          (HTTP)  Maximum  time in seconds that you allow curl to wait for a
          100-continue response when curl emits an Expects: 100-continue
          header in its request. By default curl will wait one second. This 
          option accepts decimal values! When curl stops  waiting, it will
          continue as if the response has been received.

          (Added in 7.47.0)
```

So, if you have a new-enough version it appears that cURL will "continue as if the response has been received". If you don't have a new enough version, `Expect` is an HTTP 1.1 header so sending the request as HTTP 1.0 should resolve the problem.

Comment: actually this is not quite right - expect should be handled by PHP script so that script can decide if to allow this request or deny based on whatever the logic or parameters which server will not and should not be aware of.

Comment: No, the HTTP server handles low level protocol details like that. PHP decides whether to serve the file based on the initial request.

Comment: No, kindly refer to IETF discussions, the whole intention behind the EXPECT was to let receiving node decides before client can send large body, for example a large upload.

Comment: That's interesting, I wasn't aware of the intention behind it. I'd be curious to see if the web server (Apache or Nginx) passes that on to PHP and allows it to respond; I may have to add to this answer. Thanks!